# Pushing back response date of time sensitive offer

Tags: job-offer, negotiation

I asked for an advance on salary. They said they will check with their colleagues and hopefully let me know tomorrow about whether they give it or not. However, last week I told them that today I would get back to them regarding the offer letter which is time sensitive, but I don't want to accept the offer letter before they get back to me about the advance on salary, even though I will accept the offer whether they give the advance on salary or not.

How can I tell them that I will respond to the offer letter when I hear back from them about the advance on salary?

Comment: @Joe Strazzere that is too direct, and is likely to come across the wrong way. Maybe them saying that they will get back to me tomorrow about the advance of salary implies that they will give me an extra day or two to respond to the offer?

Comment: @Sa2 I would just be indirect about it - Don't respond formally since you've already asked. They'll follow up asking, and just say "Hi, yes i was told I'd get a response to some questions i had about a salary advance tomorrow, I should be able to provide you a formal answer then."

Comment: @Joe Strazzere on second thought, that's a fine answer.

Comment: @schizoid94 is "Hi, yes i was told I'd get a response to some questions i had about a salary advance tomorrow, I should be able to provide you a formal answer then." meant as a response if they ask why I didn't respond to the offer today?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to accept either way, you need to go ahead and accept now.

You have already made a bit of extra work for them with the advance.  That's fine, but every additional high maintenance thing you do adds up.  Don't do them for no actual outcome difference. They may just decide to go with an alternate candidate if you have too many demands during the hiring process.

You should call them up today and ask if they have an answer, and when it might be expected if not, but then not accepting the position just to - what, sweat them? - isn't a good idea.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the last paragraph is saying. Maybe you can rephrase it?

Comment: Oh, you mean that I'm not accepting the position just to pressure them into giving me an advance?

Comment: It’s the only reason in evidence.

Answer (score 0):

> However, last week I told them that today I would get back to them regarding the offer letter which is time sensitive,

Then that's what you should do. Don't break a commitment you've already made.

> but I don't want to accept the offer letter before they get back to me about the advance on salary, even though I will accept the offer whether they give the advance on salary or not.

That makes no sense. You've already decided to accept, so accept!

> How can I tell them that I will respond to the offer letter when I hear back from them about the advance on salary?

You don't. You are using the threat of withholding your acceptance to accelerate the decision on the advance. That's a bad idea. You entangle two administrative processes that don't need to be entangled. In most organizations that creates creates delay and confusions and you may be at risk losing your offer about that.

It can also create a bad impression: to me this type of behavior comes across as immature, pushy, and also as a severe lack of organizational awareness.

Comment: Organizational awareness? Anyways this answer is very late.